Spam In Terminal and code editors ^[[2~^[[2~^[[2~^[[2~^[[2~^
I’m encountering an issue with my Ubuntu system where unwanted characters like ^[[2~^[[2~^[[2~^[[2~^[[2~ start spamming in the terminal whenever I begin typing. This issue continues until I press another key, which seems to stop the spam temporarily. A keyboard tester shows that the Insert key is spamming.
Additionally, when using text editors or code editors, I notice that it automatically toggles between Overwrite mode and Insert mode. This toggling occurs erratically and is likely related to the Insert key issue.
Here’s a summary of the problems:
Terminal: Characters like ^[[2~ appear repeatedly when typing.
Text Editors/Code Editors: The editor switches between Overwrite mode and Insert mode automatically.
I’ve tried restarting the system and adjusting key mappings using xmodmap, but the problem remains unresolved.
Has anyone faced a similar issue or have suggestions on how to fix this? Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Tried using a different keyboard?

Sounds as if it could also have to do with hardware. Is this a laptop or a desktop? If it's a laptop, to troubleshoot, you might need to find a way to disable the internal keyboard?

As others say, the problem is the key. Start by cleaning your keyboard. Failing that,  if it’s external, try another. If laptop (internal), hopefully vacuuming/ careful cleaning might help … if not, you’ll have to disable & use external, or replace it.
